# Xamarin iOS App deployment

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

The docs from Xamarin aren't explicit as to where an iOS device needs to be attached. I'm using VS to build a Xamarin app through a remote Mac Builder (connected via VPN) but my iphone is attached to my PC with Visual Studio. Its completely unclear as to whether or not you can deploy a compiled to from the PC you're running Visual Studio on or whether the iOS device needs to be USB'd to the remote Mac running the build.

Comment: My question is that, i am developing iOS app using xamarin and i have a mac connected in the the LAN as an Agent.
But i want to deploy the App to an actual device and test it.

Comment: Official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I have already created the developer account and added code signing too. But  i have connected the device(iphonw) to the PC where the Visual Studio is installed. And I want to know how to access the iphone on the mac side

Comment: If your phone is connected to the computer with your visual studio on it and your PC is connected to your mac, you should see your phone show up in the debug panel where you select devices

Comment: I have connected the device directly to the MAC and then set it up for WIFI debugging then unplugged it. Then now I can see the device on the debug list on the windows pc visual studio.

I have already done that part. Now am looking for a way on how to debug using the device without having a paid developer account. I already created the developer account but not a paid one.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Xamarin offers developers the way to use C# creating native iOS applications, we also need to pair to a Mac which is required for compiling native iOS applications. So of course if you want to deploy on a real device, you need to connect it to the Mac.

It seems you have already known how to create a provisioning profile. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) tells you how to pair to a Mac to deploy applications. Also before doing that you also need to complete the following steps:

> - On a Windows machine, install Visual Studio 2017
> - On a Mac, install    Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: I have already done that part. Now am looking for a way on how to debug using the device without having a paid developer account

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning) to use a free provisioning.

Comment: The thing is that, i have already checked this link. Since the device is visible under the list of debugging devices, I am trying to debug my app from the windows pc visual studio not from the Xcode side. I am looking for a way to do that from my windows pc

Comment: Once you have successfully install the provisioning on your mac and deploy an application with your device using XCode. You can find this device on your windows pc too.

Comment: - i can see my device on the list    
- when debugging the ios app via  the device, "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com"

Comment: You just see the device, but you didn't install a vaild code signing on your Mac so you can't deploy your project on a real device. As I said above you need to use XCode or VS for Mac to `Automatically manage signing`, then you can use vs for windows to deploy on the real device.